# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP applied after waiting for lock - what is the value?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, mariadb, innodb

In a scenario where an InnoDB insert/update statement must wait for a transaction to complete, what is the value used for NOW() and/or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Is it the value from when the data was ready to be inserted/updated but started waiting for the lock to be released, or from when the changes were actually applied? I can't find anything explaining this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see  in mysql doc the main diff is between the use of now() (and current_timestamp )  and SYSDATE().

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger,
>   NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement
>   began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for SYSDATE(), which
>   returns the exact time at which it executes.

You can find some ref.. here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now